# Missing required parameters for [Route: login] [URI: {lang}/login]. when i try to access routes with auth middleware

Tags: laravel

when i try to access routes as guests with Auth middle ware it says that   `Missing required parameters for [Route: login] [URI: {lang}/login].` this is because i added localization to my website.
here is my home controller

> class HomeController extends Controller
> {
> /**
> * Create a new controller instance.
> *
> * @return void
> */
> public function __construct()
> {
> $this->middleware('auth');
> $this->middleware('verified');
> }

```
/**
 * Show the application dashboard.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
 */
public function index($lang)
{
   \App::setlocale($lang);

   return view('home');
    }
```

this is my authenticate.php middleware

```
protected function redirectTo($request)
{
    if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
        return route('login' , app()->getLocale());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try after changing `App::setlocale($lang)` to `App::setLocale($lang)` in your index method. getLocale as of now is probably empty (but setlocale should have thrown an error if I'm not mistaken)

```
protected function redirectTo($request)
{
if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
     return route('login' , app()->getLocale()); //getLocale probably return empty value
 }
}
```

Comment: i dont understand

Comment: Wait do you setLocale in index methid only?

Comment: You need to set it globally  either in session or apply it with each request in the app service provider or a middleware or anywhere where locale could always be set

Answer (score 0):

```
return route('login', ['lang' => app()->getLocale()])
```

You should pass the parameter of `lang` like this, inside an array of parameters.

Comment: Did you run `php artisan config:cache` before trying?

Comment: Then check if you actually set the language. The issue is probably in the setLocale function.